# Chinese characters sent from ksoap2 converts to "?????" on php server side

Tags: android, web-services, soap, android-ksoap2

Data sent from android using ksoap2 converts chinese characters in to ???? on server side.

```
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.encodingStyle = "UTF-8";
        envelope.dotNet = false;
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(ServiceConstants.NAME_SPACE, methodName);


        //Pass value for user name variable of the web service
        PropertyInfo mapIdProp =new PropertyInfo();
        mapIdProp.setName("mapID");//Define the variable name in the web service method
        mapIdProp.setValue(map_id);//Define value for user name variable
        mapIdProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
        request.addProperty(mapIdProp);//Pass properties to the variable

        //Pass value for user name variable of the web service
        try {
            PropertyInfo mapStringProp = new PropertyInfo();
            mapStringProp.setName("mapstring");//Define the variable name in the web service method
            mapStringProp.setValue(mapString);//Define value for user name variable
            mapStringProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
            request.addProperty(mapStringProp);//Pass properties to the variable
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(url);
    String response_string;
    try {
        ArrayList<HeaderProperty> headerProperty = new ArrayList<HeaderProperty>();

        headerProperty.add(new HeaderProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml"));
        headerProperty.add(new HeaderProperty("charset", "UTF-8"));
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope,headerProperty);
        response_string = (String) envelope.getResponse();
        if(response_string!=null){
            Log.d("AsyncCall", "----Response is---"+response_string);
            return response_string;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("AsyncCall", "----Response not received---");
    }
```

My mapstring data is posted in chinese format : 汉字/漢字 . Data is sent in chinese format but on server side it automatically get converted to ????.
My soap webservice is already encoded in UTF-8 charset